# How to fix rake db:migrate and db:migrate:status doing nothing

Tags: ruby, sqlite, activerecord, sinatra

Yesterday, using `rake db:migrate` I was able to create the database, schema and tables automatically.

Today it is not working anymore, with no error at all. Also, it will not do these things:

- `rake rake db:migrate SINATRA_ENV=development`
- `rake db:migrate:status`

Trace:

```
laura\ test15-database$  rake db:migrate SINATRA_ENV=development --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

I am only able to use `rake db:create_migration Name="XX"`.

I also tried:

```
rake db:drop:all
rake db:create:all
rake db:migrate
```

but those only create an empty database inside my database folder.

My migration file is:

```
class Ships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ships do |t|
     t.string :name
     t.string :category
     t.string :booty
     t.integer :pirate_id
  end
end
```

I have no idea what is happening. I already read all the questions here and couldn't find a solution or how to get an error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages. Properly formatting your text is very important on SO. It helps others read, and understand, your question more easily. Help is available in the edit box and is discussed in these pages: "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
and "[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)"

Comment: are you using spring? sometimes it can store an invalid cache and start causing wtf errors, if so try running `spring stop`

Comment: Thank, it is a bug or something form active record 6.0, I changed the gem version and started to work fine.